Error with RPi.GPIO "Runtime Error: Waiting for EDGE"
I'm using an Raspberry Pi 4 Model B for this code
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

# GPIO-Pin für den Klingelknopf
KLINGEL_PIN = 18

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(KLINGEL_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Initialisierung der USB-Kamera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Zeitdauer, wie lange das Bild nach dem Klingeln angezeigt werden soll (in Sekunden)
ANZEIGEZEIT = 10  # in dem Fall 10 Sekunden

def zeige_bild():
    # Erstellen eines Vollbildfensters
    cv2.namedWindow("Live-Feed", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("Live-Feed", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

    # Starten des Live-Feeds
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        cv2.imshow("Live-Feed", frame)

        # Warten auf eine Taste zum Beenden (oder eine bestimmte Zeit)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q') or time.time() > endzeit:  # Zum Beenden 'q' drücken oder Zeit abgelaufen
            break

    # Schließen des Live-Feed-Fensters
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def zeige_leeres_bild():
    # Erstellen eines Vollbildfensters
    cv2.namedWindow("Schwarzbild", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("Schwarzbild", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

    # Erstellen eines schwarzen Bildes
    schwarzbild = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Anzeigen des schwarzen Bildes
    cv2.imshow("Schwarzbild", schwarzbild)
    
    # Startzeit für die Überprüfung der Tastatureingabe
    startzeit = time.time()
    
    # Warten auf eine Taste oder das Drücken von 'q'
    while True:
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')
            break
    
    # Schließen des Fensters für das schwarze Bild
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            # Warten auf Klingel-Impuls
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(KLINGEL_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
            print("Klingel gedrückt, Live-Feed wird gestartet...")

            # Zeige das Bild für eine bestimmte Zeit
            global endzeit
            endzeit = time.time() + ANZEIGEZEIT
            zeige_bild()

            print("Live-Feed beendet.")

            # Nach dem Schließen des Live-Feeds zeige ein schwarzes Bild
            zeige_leeres_bild()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        # Aufräumen
        GPIO.cleanup()
        cap.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This code is supossed to detect an elektrical impulse on Pin 18 an activate an livefeed of an USB-Webcam. This code worked completely fine. After I finished working with the Pi I layed it aside for two weeks and no one had acces to the Pi. Atfer these two weeks I had to install the Pi for an projekt, which then just stopped working. The following Error appears when starting the code:
[ WARN:0@2.422] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1405) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raspi/Desktop/kamera-Impuls_test4.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/raspi/Desktop/kamera-Impuls_test4.py", line 70, in main
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(KLINGEL_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
RuntimeError: Error waiting for edge

------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue

The GStreamer warning is not the problem, that error accured before, but those two traceback lines, im slowly starting to loose my mind because of that error.
Things I tried so far:

ReInstalling the entire Pi
Using a different Pi
Installing an older version of RPi.GPIO
Installing an older version of pip
Changing the used GPIO Pin
Checking if root permissions/rights are correct (they are)
Logging (the only thing logs showed me: "DEBUG:root:Warte auf Klingel-Impuls")
Reinstall RPi.GPIO (this step was weird, because in the path this package should be installed in doesnt exist. When I deleted it, the package was deleted succesfully from the path that doesnt seem to exist, but when I try to isntall the package right after it says "Requirement already satisfied..."


IIUC, RPi.GPIO relies on the sysfs GPIO interface for its edge detection, and sysfs has recently been removed from Pi kernels.  Did you update your kernel?  You might want to try rolling back to an older kernel.
